# How to get perfect linear gradient?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to create a linear gradient controlled by `Angle`, and `Tilt`. However the gradient doesn't look linear.

[image]

The bottom image is the correct linear gradient at 45 deg.

[image]

Comment: 1. Why do you expect a linear gradient when you have set it to _Quadratic_ instead of _Linear_? 2. The appearance of the (correct) linear gradient also depends on the _Color Management_ settings.

Comment: The question is ambigous. Do you want the gradient to start at a corner, as opposed to $1$ away from the center (because it started on the left edge, and you rotated it), or do you want the gradient to be linear instead of quadratic, as pointed out by Lolmerkat, or do you want it to LOOK linear, in which case you probably should switch from Filmic to sRGB color transformation in output settings…

Comment: The problem is anyway that when you want it to go from 0 at the bottom left corner to 1 in the top right corner, this will not work with _Generated_ coordinates rotated by 45°. Because the coordinates range from 0 to 1 in X, Y and Z direction. But if you rotate them by 45°, the diagonal is longer than the plane's dimensions, which means apart from choosing a quadratic interpoaltion the 0 to 1 range is not starting/ending at the corners as you can see by combining two _Math_ nodes with _Less Than 1_ and _Greater Than 0_: [0 to 1 range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R92op.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the *Generated* texture coordinates will always be 0 to 1 on X, Y and Z no matter what size the object is (assuming the scale of an object is applied).

This means, when you take those coordinates and the X values go from 0 to 1 horizontally, then the distance diagonally will correspond to $\sqrt{2}$, starting at the center. Also the *Gradient Texture* will only output values from 0 to 1, so everything below 0 will be 0 as well and above 1 is clamped to 1:

[image: limits of gradient texture]

So what you need to do is get rid of the *Gradient Texture* and instead take a *Separate XYZ* node and get the X output (when you've set the *Vector Rotate* like you did, *Center* can stay at [0, 0, 0] by the way). Then take a *Map Range* node and set the *From Min* to 0, *From Max* value to $\sqrt{2}$ and map them to *To Min* = 0 and *To Max* = 1. And for the *Color Management* to have the gradient look as linear as you expect it, set the *View Transform* to *Raw* and *Look* to *None*.

[image: using map range node]

Comment: It worked, but what I have to do to get similar result in `View Transform = Standard`

Comment: Try to manually adjust it for example with a _Color Ramp_ so it pleases your eyes. _View Transform_ is as the name says just a transformation of the view. The mathematical values are exactly the same, it is just how they are displayed. You could adjust it by reducing the _Gamma_ value, but this will affect the whole view, not just the gradient.

Answer (score 4):

You have set the mode of the Gradient Texture node set to *Quadratic* instead of *Linear*.

If this still doesn't match your expectations I would suggest using a colour ramp node which has some more customizability in terms of gradient points and color.