# How to add gradient and rotate each cell of the grid?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to add a gradient to each cell and rotate each grid cell.

The grid is currently separated into `Less Than` and `Greater Than` nodes.

Since the grid is separated there is input `Gradient Less Than` to control the gradient amount for cells which is less than `0.5` and input `Gradient Greater Than` to control the gradient amount for cells that is greater than `0.5`.

In the same way the input `Angle Less Then` should control the rotation for cells which is less than `0.5` and input `Angle Greater Then` should control the rotation for cells that are greater than `0.5`

Note: The rotation of gradients should be random for each cell.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A bit similar [to the Wizard's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308597/35559), but this time using the random-per-cell value that Voronoi gives us in 'Color':

[image]

Ooops.. The *Multiply* is by `2*pi` (or `tau`)

The cluster on the left, above, gives rotated UV's per-cell, as illustrated on the left, below:

[image]

The center example shows a square image rotated by the cluster and shifted appropriately.. the right example shows an X gradient in the same frame, again shifted in the (rotated) coordinates, to put black at X = -0.5

[image]

Comment: At first I wanted to use the Color, but I was worried the distribution will be gaussian like with Noise Texture: https://i.imgur.com/hYQsSFi.png - but I just checked, and for voronoi the distribution is even: https://i.imgur.com/NY1EnX6.png - testing with this setup: https://i.imgur.com/gcRO933.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  I was trepidatious posting under you..  I  _knew_  there must be a reason the Mage hadn't gone for it.. and he's  tested! I'm so lazy.. I've just used it so often, and seen others do the same, I never questioned that. Great work to settle it for sure.. and a Happy Xmas, MVB!

Comment: I only tested after your answer, and your approach is the better (simpler) one, Merry xmas!

Comment: Awesome node compositing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *Voronoi* texture for that:

[image]

If you don't want any flat color, as explained by [Gordon Brinkmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308491/60486) in your other question, you need to normalize the range

Comment: Great work of node tree